# Run a command for all files in a directory

Tags: python, python-2.x

I have a program that needs to run an command on all the files in a folder:

```
import glob
import os

dirName = "../pack"

if not os.path.exists(dirName):
    os.mkdir(dirName)

os.chdir("xml/")

files = []
for file in glob.glob("*.xml"):
    files.append(file)

os.chdir("..")

filearchiver_cmdline = "archiver.exe"

for myFile in files:
    filearchiver_cmdline += " xml\\" + myFile

os.system( filearchiver_cmdline )
```

The command should look like this:

```
Arhiver.exe file1.xml
```

What should I change / optimize for this code? Would a class be needed? Should there be logical def-s? Are the variables name good?

Comment: Hi nansy. This post is being discussed on meta: https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9165/posted-answer-asker-deletes-question-what-do

Answer (score 4):

1. Looping over `glob.glob` to build files is unneeded.
2. You shouldn't need to `chdir` if you change the glob to `xml/*.xml`
3. `filearchiver_cmdline` can be changed to use `str.join` and a comprehension.

<sub>**Note**: untested</sub>

```py
import glob
import os

dir_name = "../pack"

if not os.path.exists(dir_name):
    os.mkdir(dir_name)

os.system(" ".join(
    ["archiver.exe"]
    + ["xml\\" + f for f in glob.glob("xml/*.xml")]
))
```